# Padding для UITextField[решен]

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Есть `UITextField`  с 2мя элементами(rightView и leftView):

```
label.text = @"Ваш пол";
clientGender.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
clientGender.leftView = label;

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
clientGender.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
clientGender.rightView = imageView;
```

Вопрос: как сделать внутренний отступ для текстового поля, т.к. leftView(надпись "Ваш пол") — налезает на textview

UPD. Вопрос решен путем создания подкласса для UITextField с таким вот извратом :/

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];

    if (self) {

        self.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [self setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing];
        [self setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing];

        //self.leftView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"textfield_edit_icon.png"]];
    }

    return self;
}

- (CGRect) rightViewRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {

    CGRect textRect = [super rightViewRectForBounds:bounds];
    textRect.origin.x -= 10;
    return textRect;
}

- (CGRect) leftViewRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    CGRect textRect = [super leftViewRectForBounds:bounds];
    textRect.origin.x += 10;
    return textRect;
}

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds{
    CGRect textRect = [super textRectForBounds:bounds];
    textRect.origin.x += 0;
    textRect.size.width -= 10;
    return textRect;
}
```

Comment: Во первых не понятно зачем тут TextView? во-вторых не почему не используете автолайауты и констрайны?

Comment: Мне определенно нужен ликбез по автолейаутам. Я их отключаю, т.к. я где-то прочитал что их нужно выключать.

На самом деле я делаю текстовое поле у которого слева написано - "Ваш пол", по середине - выбранный пол из пикера, и справа рисунок стрелочки.

Надеюсь понятно объяснил:)

Comment: то что Вы описали больше походит на UITableViewCell в стиле UITableViewCellStyleValue1 со включеным disclousure индикатором. 
по поводу лигбеза просто прочитайте: http://www.amazon.com/Auto-Layout-Demystified-Mobile-Programming-ebook/dp/B00C68XS0S Очень четко и ясно написано.